# Import XML and create directories C#

Tags: c#, xml, path

I'm still at the beginning with XML files. I want to create directories with an XML and I have this function:

RunCommand is a function which execute comanda_cmd 
first, second are strings

```
private void ProcesNode(XmlNode node, string parentPath, string path, string first, string second, string BuiltUnit, string item)
{

    if (!node.HasChildNodes || ((node.ChildNodes.Count == 2) && (node.FirstChild is System.Xml.XmlText)))
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(parentPath + "/" + node.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            comanda_cmd = first + "/" + parentPath + second + "/" + parentPath + "/" + node.Name;
            string status = RunCommand(comanda_cmd + "/project.pj /n");
            //content = "_GEN_PROJECT/" + ProjectName + "/" + BuiltUnit + "/" + item + "/" + parentPath + "/" + node.Name + " already exist";
            //MessageBox.Show(content);
            //check_status(status, content);
            ProcesNode(child, parentPath + "/" + node.Name, path, first, second, BuiltUnit, item);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this XML:

```
<unit>
<Unit1>
    <src>
        <i>
            <test1>
                <test_in1>
                    <test_in_out>
                        <t>
                        </t>
                    </test_in_out>
                </test_in1>
            </test1>
            <test2>
                <test_in2>
                </test_in2>
            </test2>
        </i>
    </src>
    <doc>
        <i>
            <test1>
                <test_in1>
                    <test_in_out>
                        <t>
                        </t>
                    </test_in_out>
                </test_in1>
            </test1>
            <test2>
                <test_in2>
                </test_in2>
            </test2>
        </i>
    </doc>
</Unit1>
<Unit2>
    <src>
        <i>
        </i>
    </src>
</Unit2>

</unit>
```

I call ProcesNode, and it creates the directories. For example: unit/Unit1/src/i/test1/test_in1/test_in_out
but the last directory (in my case "t") is not created.

Where am I wrong? Why does it not create the last directory?

Comment: For the lowest tags (`<t>`) the `if` condition `(!node.HasChildren || ...)` is `true`, so you don't enter the  `else` block that creates the directories.

Comment: You are right! 
Thank enormous Rene Vogt

Answer (score 0):

The tags on the lowest level (like your `<t>` tag) do not have any child nodes.

Thatswhy your `if` statement

```
if (!node.HasChildNodes || ((node.ChildNodes.Count == 2) && (node.FirstChild is System.Xml.XmlText)))
```

is `true` (because `!node.HasChildNodes` is `true). So for the tags on the last level you never enter the`else` block that (presumably) creates the directories.

It seems you could simply leave that part (`!node.HasChildNodes ||`) out. The `foreach` loop will not be entered if there are no child nodes.